# add formula in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want create a new table from the existing table.

This is existing table

```
A       B               C     
title   view_count  date   

aaa      24      5/18/13    
bbb      10      5/18/13    
ccc      10      5/18/13    
aaa      10      5/19/13    
aaa      20      5/20/13    
bbb      10      5/20/13    
ccc      20      5/20/13    
ccc      20      5/21/13    
aaa       5      5/22/13    
bbb       3      5/22/13    
ccc       1      5/22/13
```

I try to make new table as follows:

```
title  date1(5/18/13)    date2(5/19/13)    date3(5/20/13)

aaa      24 (view_count)      10                20
```

How can I make this in MySQL?

=======================
I add my question. I've tried these queries you help, and then I got results what I want. 
Can I make them as a new table? 
I want to make a new table as these results.

Comment: How are Excel and mysql related in this case?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The "new table" which you describe is a poor design and will be harder to work with than the original table. You would be better to just use queries against the original table to get whatever information you need.

Comment: you want what amounts to a pivot query. mysql does not support these. you'd be better off fetching just a normal title/date/count multi-row result and doing the columnization in your client app.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT...OP changed his question while I was answering it,

`SUMIFS()`Can Help!

I use this a lot as I lookup and return data all day. It allows you to return a value from a range where a one or more certain criteria from a range is true. Works great with data structured like yours.

If your headers in row 1 are as shown with the data in row 2 and Your `Today` date  is in F1, then the formula you can type in column D2 and drag down would be...

```
=(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,$F$1-1)-SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,$F$1-2))/(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,$F$1-1))
```

You can change the value of cell F1 with the excel function `Today()` and or just put Today into your formula.

I hope this helps.

-Schebealls

[image]

Comment: Op needs to do that in **`mysql`** and not in excel

Comment: He edited the OP while I was answering it. Should maybe delete my answer?

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I want to get this answer. But I could not get it, so I changed my question. This is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```
select title,
       sum(case `date` when '2013/05/18' then view_count else 0 end) `date1(5/18/13)`,
       sum(case `date` when '2013/05/19' then view_count else 0 end) `date2(5/19/13)`,
       sum(case `date` when '2013/05/20' then view_count else 0 end) `date3(5/20/13)`
from myTable
group by title
```

- to return values for all titles; if you only want to see results for title aaa, then replace `group by title` with `where title='aaa'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **`Query`**

```
select 
    distinct
    t.title,
    t1.view_count as `date1(5/18/13)`,
    t2.view_count as `date2(5/19/13)`,
    t3.view_count as `date2(5/20/13)`
from table_name t
left join table_name t1 on t.title=t1.title and t1.date='2013/5/18'
left join table_name t2 on t.title=t2.title and t2.date='2013/5/19'
left join table_name t3 on t.title=t3.title and t3.date='2013/5/20'
where t.title='aaa'
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b343/2)**